# mediaelements.js update the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I would like to pull the chapter markers out of the mejs-layers element and place them elsewhere on the page. In the `mep-feature-tracks.js` file I've found where the element is `.prependTo` (line 55). I've tried messing with this line, `.append` and changing the target, but it's not creating any affect(effect?).

Here's the line

```
player.chapters =
                $('<div class="mejs-chapters mejs-layer"></div>')
                    .prependTo(layers).hide();
```

Usually I would be console.loggin things out, but nothing is printing to the console. So, so help with debugging would be good too.

I am `grunt` building the player and making changes in the `/src` directory.

Hindsite is 20/20 and as soon as I posted this question I realized I'd never deleted that line completely to test whether this was generating the captions. At least for this player it's not. I commented out that line and rebuilt and nothing changed. Hm.